# Salesforce number field default value to (highest number in a record) + 1

Tags: salesforce, field

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm trying to make a field for an account number. It will be a unique number that increases. But I would like its default value to be an increment from the highest number of current records since I'm going to import data and those data have some unused account numbers in between.
For example, I have a data with account numbers: 1, 4, 10, 13, 14 -> then the next one's default value would be 14 + 1 = 15.

What's the simplest solution to this? I tried MAX(Account_Number) + 1, but it's not allowing me to use its own value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once and solved it by setting the field as an auto-increment and then creating and deleting large quantities of records to reach my starting number.

If you are importing and want to retain the previous values, this will not work, unfortunately.

You can use a trigger or flow to populate the account number after a record is created.

For the quick and dirty, make a flow and call it from a process builder. If you have the ability to use sandbox and create a trigger, by all means.

Essentially, you would query the sObject with `SORT BY AccountNumber__c DESC LIMIT 1` (or whatever the field is named) and access that highest value and increment it and use that to set the value of the record you are creating.

Makes sense?